# How to create a loop that deletes empty strings within a list, whilst keeping the strings with content inside of them?

Tags: python, loops

I have a list named `player_home_run`, and the way that my program works is that sometimes, empty string is entered to it, and sometimes, words and other strings are entered into it. After a loop, the string sometimes looks like this:

`['', '', '', '', 'Perez', '', '', '', 'Guerrero']`

I would like to make a small loop that would delete all the empty spaces and leave me with only the names in the string. The length of the string should be the same as the # of names.

Should look like this:

```
['Perez', 'Guerrero']
```

I want to avoid using filter.

Edit: I figured out the ans right after posting this question.

Here's the code

```
            if hit == True:
            print(player_home_run, '# of homeruns')
            run_calc = True
            while run_calc == True:
                if '' in player_home_run:
                    player_home_run.remove('')
                    ttl_runs = player_home_run
                else:
                    print('no more whitespace.')
                    print(ttl_runs, ' ttl runs')
                    run_calc = False
```

Comment: This algorithm is really slow. I suggest instead using a for loop directly over the list and build up a new list with the names you want to keep rather than thinking of the strings you want to delete.

Answer (score 2):

You could do a comprehension, like:

```
player_home_run = [item for item in player_home_run if item != ""]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do a loop, then simply qualifying each iteration with an if statement will suffice. Here is an example:

```
listA = ['', '', '', '', 'Perez', '', '', '', 'Guerrero']
listB = []
for item in listA:
    if item != "":
        listB.append(item)
listA = listB
print listA
```

Here is the output for this script:

```
['Perez', 'Guerrero']
```